# How to compile module package in build gradle?

Tags: java

I'am trying to compile a package folder in build.gradle in android studio .and when I sync error show "Error:(29, 0) Supplied String module notation 'com.google.activities.components.runtime.ListPickerActivity' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.
build gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "store.muha.com.freequranapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.activities.components.runtime.ListPickerActivity'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: What follows `compile` is supposed to be the coordinates of a library in a repository (group id, artifact id, version). gradle downloads this library and its pom.xml, and add it and its dependencies to the compilation classpath when building your project. You're passing the fully qualified name of a class. That makes no sense.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for response .so is there a way to compile this package ?